# What happens if I call a java function from multiple threads from C with JNI?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, pthreads

This link seems to suggest that "it just works": (pretty far on the bottom under 7.3 Attaching Native Threads) http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/invoke.html

I don't see how that is possible, is the embedded JVM going to start its own threads automatically? Or queue the JNI calls? How else could there be multiple calls to the same virtual machine. which I haven't instructed to do any threading?

Any way I can imagine that to work is, if the java code will simply be executed in the same calling thread as the c code. Is that correct? That would mean that I don't have to do any threading in Java.

Comment: As for the article that you linked, you don't have to do any threading in Java. Another question is if the JVM does create its own separate thread or just uses the original thread (I am betting on the latter, though).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jvm does not have to create its own threads, the method calls are executed on the native threads that make them. The AttachCurrentThread and DetachCurrentThread will take care of any necessary jvm internal state management, for example creating java Thread objects wrapping the native threads.

Comment: Yes, I just found this on Wikipedia: `Once attached, a native thread works like a regular Java thread running within a native method. The native thread remains attached to the VM until it calls DetachCurrentThread() to detach itself.`

Answer (score 0):

The JVM starts its own threads which it needs to run. You trigger this thread creation by starting the JVM.